# How to playback Wiremock in java?

Tags: java, wiremock

I have been trying to playback the recordings in java that are done before .I gave my path to mappings and recordings to WiremockServer and then used enableRecordMappings() method for recording .It is able to record mappings in my specified path. But when I try to playback with new server, how to tell it to look for my path for recordings? 
I even copied my mappings and __files folders into WEB-INF/wiremock as said in documentation,but it is not replaying.Can some one help me here?
I am using below code for recording

```
WireMockServer wmServer = new WireMockServer(httpPort, httpsPort);
wmServer.enableRecordMappings(mappings, files);               
wmServer.stubFor(any(urlMatching(".*")).willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("https://10.122.45.65")));
wmServer.start();
```

I am taking inputs from a xml file .All variables are initialized correctly.

Comment: Can you please add relevant part of your code here?

Comment: added now.Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
wmServer.loadMappingsUsing(new JsonFileMappingsSource(mappings));
```

the problem, it need to have files in folder ~/test/resources/__files/*

Comment: Actually starting server from the same location loads the mappings automatically. It worked for me.